# CONFIG_KVM=m in my .config, but why is KVM in the output of lsmod?

Tags: drivers, kernel, configuration, kvm-virtualization

I just viewed the .config of ubuntu in /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic/.config. 
There is CONFIG_KVM=m. But when I use lsmod, kvm moudle is in the output. CONFIG_XX=m means that the moudule is not compiled into the kernel. You can use "modprobe xxx.ko" to load the module. lsmod shows which loadable kernel modules are currently loaded.

But my CONFIG_KVM=m and I do not use modprobe. Why is KVM in the output of lsmod?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As describe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555375/on-most-linux-systems-why-is-the-kvm-kernel-module-loaded-even-when-youre-not) kvm is automaticaly loaded on boot on cpus which support hardware virtualization.

If you don't need virtualization you can disable VT-d/AMD-V in your BIOS to prevent module kvm to load on boot

***Update:***

Build as module allows you to have a faster boot by loading only specific features onboot. It does not guarantee to you that a module will not be loaded. If a ressource need this module it could be loaded directly by the binary like `iptables` does.

**Example:**
`nf_conntrack` is an iptables modules which allows you to track connections through the firewall `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m`. This module will not be loaded unless you add a rule using `-m conntrack`.

**Other example:**

My computer have an ethernet card using driver `e1000`.

`grep CONFIG_E1000 /boot/config-4.15.0-91-generic`

```
CONFIG_E1000=m
CONFIG_E1000E=m
CONFIG_E1000E_HWTS=y
```

It shows me the `e1000` driver is built as module.

Using `modinfo e1000 | alias` will gives all aliases that will load the kernel module automatically

```
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E6Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001099sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
...
```

Since my ethernet card is an intel (VendorID 8086) it matches to the alias, so the module is loaded as shown in `dmesg`

```
[    1.520584] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
```

All the modules you see in `lsmod` after a fresh boot were used during the boot process.

Comment: So except KVM, other modules should not in the output of lsmod, if their CONFIG=m, not y ?

Comment: Build as module allows you to have a faster boot by loading only specific features onboot. It does not guarantee to you that a module will not be loaded. If a ressource need this module it could be loaded directly by the binary like `iptables` does.

Comment: can you give more details about iptables?

Comment: I've edited my previous answer

Comment: I want to confirm: if a module's CONFIG_XXX=m, it does not mean that the module will not be loaded automatically on boot. Also, if you do not use modprobe, some CONFIG_XXX=m module can still be in the output of lsmod. Thanks

Comment: Exactly, build a kernel feature as module does not guarantee it will not be load on boot. Features build as modules will be load on the fly when they are needed.

Comment: But it seems that modules like KVM which is loaded on boot and CONFIG_KVM=m is little. Do you know other modules which is similiar to KVM? Most modules will not be loaded on boot if their CONFIG=m. They are loaded when  modprobe is used or other program needs them.

Comment: If i'm not wrong all the network drivers are modules, like kvm they are loaded using aliasing. I'll update my main answer to add details.

Comment: I understand now.  The aliases of a module states  kind of hardware supported by the modules. If a hardware meets one aliase of a module, the module will be loaded automatically on boot.

Comment: Glad I could help you